# Scrolling PAST the bottom row of a DataGridView

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, scroll

Is there some property or method to set the vertical scroll position of a `DataGridView` **past** the bottom row?

What I mean is, say I have a `DataGridView` with enough rows to fill its client area. Then (by default, at least) I cannot scroll down past this point:

[image: DataGridView scrolled to bottom row]

I want to be able to *force* the control to continue scrolling, so that I can display some gray area below the bottom row. What I'm after would hypothetically look like this:

[image: DataGridView scrolled beyond bottom row]

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: @Homam: Kind of a long explanation, but... I wrote a control that splits up a `DataGridView` to take advantage of available horizontal space (https://bitbucket.org/dtao/taocontrols/downloads). I was hoping for this behavior to complement a particular setting on that control.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know there is no way of doing that short of rolling out your own custom command to display the data.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, giodamelio!

Comment: Ya answers like this do kinda suck. May i ask why you would want that?

Comment: Tough to explain without an illustration, but it's basically a "would be nice to have" sort of feature that I was looking to implement as part of a control I wrote (https://bitbucket.org/dtao/taocontrols/downloads). As it stands, I just left it out.

Answer (score 1):

How about to use `Panel` with desired size and with large `DataGridView` inside, and move internal stuff with own `ScrollBar`?

`DataGridView` may be resized by formula:

```
dataGridView1.Height =
    // Total height of all rows
    dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.None) +
    // Panel visible height
    panel1.ClientSize.Height;
```

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Test1", "Test1");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Test2", "Test2");

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("abc", "10");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("def", "20");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("ghi", "30");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("jkl", "40");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("mno", "50");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("pqr", "60");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("stu", "70");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("vwx", "80");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("yza", "90");

            UpdatePanel();
        }

        void UpdatePanel()
        {
            dataGridView1.Height = dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.None) + panel1.ClientSize.Height;
            vScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
            vScrollBar1.Maximum = dataGridView1.Height - panel1.ClientSize.Height;
        }

        private void panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdatePanel();
        }

        private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Top = -vScrollBar1.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example form]

Alternative and more easy way: set panel property `AutoScroll` to `true`, but that solution have some scrolling bugs (resets position when focus takes back). May be that bug have some workaround.